# How to modify HTML table with JavaScript to increase rowspan, without causing reflow?

Tags: javascript, dom

To change HTML table so that some cell has given rowspan="n" (to increase rowspan) you have to delete n cells below the one that is getting extended.

The original HTML source (HTML structure) looks like this

```
<table border="1">
<tr id="1"><td>1</td><td>Zubenelgenubi</td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td>2</td><td>Algorab</td></tr>
<tr id="3"><td>3</td><td>Almach</td></tr>
<tr id="4"><td>4</td><td>Alula_Borealis</td></tr>
<tr id="5"><td>5</td><td>Rigil_Kentaurus</td></tr>
<tr id="6"><td>6</td><td>Menkent</td></tr>
</table>
```

and I like to transform it to something like this:

```
<table border="1">
<tr id="1"><td>1</td><td>Zubenelgenubi</td></tr>
<tr id="2"><td>2</td><td>Algorab</td></tr>
<tr id="3" rowspan="3"><td>3</td><td>Almach</td></tr>
<tr id="4">          <td>Alula_Borealis</td></tr>
<tr id="5">          <td>Rigil_Kentaurus</td></tr>
<tr id="6"><td>6</td><td>Menkent</td></tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately SO formatting doesn't support tables, neither in Markdown, nor in HTML.

Is it possible to do it without causing unnecessary reflow?  I mean here something better than simply

```
for (var i = 0; i < numlines; i++) {
   ...
   if (i === 0) {
      td.rowSpan = numlines;
      ...
   } else {
      tr.deleteCell(0); // or td.parentNode.removeChild(td);
   }
}
```

which I think causes reflow after each iteration.

When adding elements one can use DocumentFragment; what to do when modifying number of elements at once?

---

***Edit:** added 03-05-2011*
A solution using [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) object (the W3C DOM version)

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.setStartBefore(document.getElementById(start+''));
range.setEndBefore(document.getElementById(start+numlines+''));

var fragment = range.cloneContents();

for (var i = 0; i < numlines; i++) {
    var rownum = start + i;
    var row = fragment.getElementById(rownum.toString()); // not always work

    var td = row.firstChild;
    if (i === 0) {
        td.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        td.rowSpan = num.toString();
    } else {
        td.parentNode.removeChild(td);
    }

}
range.deleteContents();

var rowAfter = document.getElementById(start+num+'');
rowAfter.parentNode.insertBefore(fragment, rowAfter);
```

Note that for some reason `fragment.getElementById` didn't work for me, so I had to cheat knowing what nodes are there.

`deleteContents` + `insertBefore` is needed because `table.replaceChild(range, fragment);` does not work, unfortunately (where `table` is element from which range was extracted).

Answer (score 3):

1. Try to make the table element display:none
   before the loop and restore the
   display after.
2. Another option would be to assign
   fixed dimensions and use
   overflow:hidden for the the time of loop body.
   This should isolate update tree by
   the table only. Theoretically.
3. And the last is to compose HTML of
   the table and replace the table as
   whole - this will be made in single
   transaction.

Comment: Ad 3: Can I use [range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range) to not to have replace whole table?